# PHP: Working with JSON API and GET

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to work with an API that's unfamiliar to me. So far my efforts to send and retrieve data have failed, and I'm hoping you can help me out.

Here are the basics of the API I'm working with:

1. I have an API key, which must be provided in an HTTP Authorization header for each request. The format should be:

   Authentication: Token token=MyApiKey
2. I need to use GET for this particular request
3. The arguments I need to pass are:

   {
   'things': {'thing1':0, 'thing2':1}
   }

I'm working with PHP and curl. I've tried a bunch of variations of things, but haven't had any success. Basically, I'm not sure how to take my variable values and pass them in the correct format.

Here's what I've been trying to do so far:

```
$token='myApiKey';

$myThings = "{ 'things': { 'thing1':0, 'thing2':1 } } ";

$url = 'http://myapiurl?' . $myThings;

$session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authentication: Token token=' . $token . ', Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');

$response = curl_exec($session);
```

Can anyone explain how to submit my values in a way that the API can understand?

Comment: Might be useful to know which API as from what you have coded you are not passing any data

Comment: Since it's GET, I thought I needed to include all the data I wanted to pass in the URL. That's where I'm not sure how to handle the json, as URL params are usually var=1&var2=2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can use http_build_query to encode for you :

```
$url = 'http://myapiurl?' . http_build_query($answers);
```

Doc is [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a JSON API where you put in normal GET parameters and get a JSON response? So in your example:

```
$url = 'http://myapiurl?'.http_build_query(json_decode($myThings));
```

If not, you would normale POST your JSON.